# Getting the page title from a scraped webpage

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var urlOpts = {host: 'www.nodejs.org', path: '/', port: '80'};
http.get(urlOpts, function (response) {
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
var str=chunk.toString();
var re = new RegExp("(<\s*title[^>]*>(.+?)<\s*/\s*title)\>", "g")
console.log(str.match(re));
});

});
```

Output

> user@dev ~ $ node app.js [ 'node.js' ] null null

I only need to get the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [`RegEx.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead of [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).  You can also define the regular expression using the literal syntax, and only once:

```
var http = require('http');
var urlOpts = {host: 'www.nodejs.org', path: '/', port: '80'};
var re = /(<\s*title[^>]*>(.+?)<\s*\/\s*title)>/gi;
http.get(urlOpts, function (response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        var str=chunk.toString();
        var match = re.exec(str);
        if (match && match[2]) {
          console.log(match[2]);
        }
    });    
});
```

The code also assumes that the `title` will be completely in one chunk, and not split between two chunks.  It would probably be best to keep an aggregation of chunks, in case the `title` is split between chunks.  You may also want to stop looking for the `title` once you've found it.

Comment: @argonius has a good point in his example, that you should probably also be using the `i` flag, in addition to `g`, to make the regular expression case insensitive (since the casing of the `<title>` tag isn't guaranteed to be lowercase, especially if the document isn't XHTML).

Comment: won't work with SPA web pages when title is set with JavaScript. You should use headless browser like google chrome

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var re = new RegExp("<title>(.*?)</title>", "i");
console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
```

Comment: `E:\╨а╨░╨▒╨╛╤З╨╕╨╣ ╤Б╤В╨╛╨╗\dev\app.js:7
console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\╨а╨░╨▒╨╛╤З╨╕╨╣ ╤Б╤В╨╛╨╗\dev\app.js:7:26)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at IncomingMessage._emitData (http.js:359:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:123:21)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1367:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:403:27)`

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!