# JS:How to turn any value to be a hyperlink via HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to turn any value added to the form to be link with title (hyperlink)

for example:

**Value**: https://www.udemy.com/

**Result (hyperlink)**: Udemy: Online Courses - Learn Anything, On Your Schedule

this is my code

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="addform">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="item" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter link">            <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addItem" type="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var value = document.getElementById('item').value;

    if (value) addItemToList(value);
});


function addItemToList(text) {

var list = document.getElementById('linkss')
var item = document.createElement('li');
item.innerHTML = text;

var buttons = document.createElement('linkss');
buttons.classList.add('buttons')

var remove = document.createElement('button');
remove.classList.add('remove');
// remove.innerHTML = removeIcon;

var add = document.createElement('button');
add.classList.add('add');

// buttons.appendChild(remove);
item.appendChild(buttons);

list.appendChild(item);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have errors in your console? `var buttons = document.createElement('linkss');` isn't a valid element to create.

Comment: Creating and adding an `<a>` is perfectly possible, but you cannot grab the website title since CORS doesn't permit AJAX  to load documents from other domains.

Comment: @skyline3000 no , please check the image I uploaded

Comment: @ChrisG so there is no way to make it !

Comment: @marrioa Correct, not without a backend (like PHP) that can grab the title.

Comment: @ChrisG I'll use firebase as backend, is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the title of a webpage given the url (an external url) using JQuery/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What you need to do

In order to do that you would have to load that page and get its `<title>` element.

#### ❌ Fetching the page from the frontend

You might *try* to do that in two different ways:

- With an AJAX GET request to get the content of the page, in which case you will get a CORS error:

  > Failed to load https://www.udemy.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

  ```js
  fetch('https://www.udemy.com');
  ```
- Using an `<iframe>`, in which case you will get an `X-Frame-Options` error:

  > Refused to display 'https://www.udemy.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

  ```html
  <iframe src="https://udemy.com" />
  ```

#### Using an API

The right way to do this would be to use a proxy/API that would make that same GET request for you, get the title of the page and send it back. For example:

- **[Textance](http://textance.herokuapp.com/)**: A simple API that will just retrieve the title of the page. This one is just an example, as you would also get an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error if you try to use it on your page.

  For example, https://textance.herokuapp.com/rest/title/http%3A%2F%2Fudemy.com returns the text:

  ```
  Online Courses - Learn Anything, On Your Schedule | Udemy
  ```
- **[URL Meta](https://urlmeta.org/)**: Another API that returns additional metadata and is **publicly available**, so you can use  this one directly from your application, but it's a bit slower and it can be down sometimes.

  For example, https://url-meta.herokuapp.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com returns the following JSON response:

  ```
  {
    "result": {
      "status": "OK"
    },
    "meta": {
      "url": "http://udemy.com",
      "type": "text/html",
      "title": "Online Courses - Learn Anything, On Your Schedule | Udemy",
      "image": "https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/images/v6/logo-coral.svg",
      "description": "Udemy is an online learning and teaching marketplace with over 65,000 courses and 15 million students. Learn programming, marketing, data science and more.",
      "favicon": "https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/images/v6/favicon-128.png",
      "feed": {
        "link": "http://udemy.com/"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

#### ✨ Working example

To use it, just make a GET request with the URL you want to get the title from. For example, using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is not supported in IE:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const list = document.getElementById('list');

document.getElementById('add').onclick = () => {
  let url = input.value;
  
  if (!url) return;
  
  if (url.indexOf('http') !== 0) {
    // Make sure the url we send always starts with http or https:
    url = `http://${ url }`;
  }
  
  // Clear input field:
  input.value = '';
  
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  
  // Create a new entry in the list indicating we are still loading the title:
  
  li.innerText = `Loading title for ${ url }...`;
  
  list.appendChild(li);
  
  // Request the actual title of that URL from the URL Meta API:
  
  fetch(`https://url-meta.herokuapp.com/?url=${ encodeURIComponent(url) }`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Once we get a response back, update the text/HTML inside the <li> we have just added
      // with the right text and <a> or an error message:
      
      if (data.result.status === 'ERROR') {
        li.innerText = `There was an error loading ${ url }: ${ data.result.reason }`;
      } else {
        li.innerHTML = `<a href="${ url }">${ data.meta.title }</a>`;
      }
    }).catch(() => {
      li.innerText = `There was an error loading ${ url }.`;
    });
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 15px;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  height: 33px;
}

#input,
#add {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: left;
}

#input {
  width: 70%;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
}

#add {
  width: 30%;
}

#input:hover,
#add:hover {
  background: #EEE;
}

#list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 35px 0 0;
}

#list > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#list > li > a {
  word-break: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<header id="menu">
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="URL" value="http://www.udemy.com" />
  <button id="add">ADD LINK</button>
</header>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

#### ️ Building your own API/proxy

Alternatively, you could implement your own proxy/API. This would be a good starting point: [Getting the page title from a scraped webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087888/getting-the-page-title-from-a-scraped-webpage)

Comment: can I count on that for my project, I'm new to API , if there is docs to follow to make it happen, I'll use firebase for the backend

Comment: @marrioa You can choose whether you prefer to use URL Meta's API or implement your own. I have updated the answer with a working example using that API and a reference to a related question that is a good starting point if you want to implement your own backend instead.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is finding a way to grab the title without CORS preventing it. One way to solve this is to use a CORS proxy, or an API that allows CORS requests and provides website info.

Here's an implementation that also fixes adding an actual link / `<a>`.

`getTitle` uses the `fetch` API to make the request and extract the title from the returned JSON.

In the click listener, the Promise returned by `getTitle` passes the title on to `addItemToList`, which does exactly that, creating the elements in the process.

Creating and adding elements is easier / less tedious with jQuery, which is required by Bootstrap anyway. I've used Vanilla JS though since you didn't use jQuery.

```js
document.getElementById('addItem').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var url = document.getElementById('item').value;
  if (url) getTitle(url).then(title => addItemToList(url, title));
});

function getTitle(url) {
  return fetch("https://api.urlmeta.org/?url=" + url).then(response => response.json()).then(info => info.meta.title);
}

function addItemToList(url, title) {

  // create <a>
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.innerHTML = title;
  a.href = url;
  a.target = "_blank";

  var list = document.getElementById('links')
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('list-group-item');

  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.classList.add('btn');
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.classList.add('float-right');
  remove.innerHTML = "X";
  let p = li;
  remove.onclick = function() {
    list.removeChild(p);
  };

  li.appendChild(a);
  li.appendChild(remove);

  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form action="" class="addform">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="url" class="form-control" id="item" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter link" value="https://udemy.com">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addItem" type="button">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul id="links" class="list-group">
  </ul>
</div>
```